# How to store variable value until change

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

I have a Javascript variable called speed with value 20 and corresponding text box and a change button. If anyone of my client change the speed value, then it should be updated for all clients. Since I cannot use database, 
how can I save the value until the next change?

Comment: Not enough info. Is this ran on a server? How is this loaded? A bit of code would be nice as well. What does clients actually mean? Individual instances on one machine or entirely different users.

Comment: You are going to have to store this information on a server so that it is in one central location. Whether you use a formal database or not is up to you. It could just be stored in a text file.

Comment: When you don't have a database, you could have a look at Sockets. Or you could save the speed variable in server memory and let the clients poll every few seconds to get the latest speed variable

Comment: @johnmathew Your variable 'speed' will be maintained in the server until its lifetime. Once the server got shutdown or crashed due to any issues, then whatever the initial value which you are setting will displayed for all the clients. If you want to persists, but don't want to use db, you can go for file system.

Comment: Is there any solution rather than using database connection ?

Comment: Depending on the technology you are using on the server, you could save and retrieve the value in the application scope. This way the value would be available as long as the server was not restarted. You could also persist the value in a file on the server, but, as I said, it all depends on the server tech you are using and the kind of access you have to its environment.